# What does the pigeonhole principle have to do with graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I am currently trying to teach myself graph theory, and in every book I've read the pigeonhole principle inevitably comes up. I understand the concept well enough, but what I fail to grasp is what a counting argument has to do with graph theory. What applications does the pigeonhole principle have in graph theory? Why is it so important?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Prove that any simple (i.e., no loops, undirected edges, no more than one edge between any pair of vertices) finite graph has at least two vertices of the same degree.

Comment: What do the graph theory books you found pigeon hole in apply it to?

Comment: The pigeonhole principle is a way of saying that if two sets $A,B$ have no injection $A\to B$ then any function $A\to B$ is not an injection. So, in a way it is not useful at all and you can always remove it in every proof that uses it. However, the process of discovering proofs can be influenced by how things are presented, discovering that some statement is equivalent to some function not being injective for convenient choices of sets $A,B$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example.

> Suppose a finite directed graph $G = (V, E)$ with at least one node has the property that for all nodes $n$, there is some edge $(n \to m) \in E$. Then there is a cycle in $G$.

Proof: Let $k = |V|$. Take some node $n \in V$. Pick a sequence $n_0, \ldots, n_k$ such that $n_0 = n$ and for all $m < k$, there is an edge $n_m \to n_{m + 1}$.

By the pidgeonhole principle, there must be some $0 \leq i < j \leq k$ such that $n_i = n_j$. Then $n_i, n_{i + 1}, \ldots, n_{j - 1}, n_j$ is a cycle. $\square$

This proves that nonempty finite directed acyclic graphs must have some node $n$ with no edges going out of it. Of course, we can take the dual graph to get that finite directed acyclic graphs must have some node $n$ with no edges going into it either. This is useful for proving that topological sorting is possible.